# redux-saga-test-plan partial assertion on put not matching

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I have a Redux saga I am trying to test with [redux-saga-test-plan](https://github.com/jfairbank/redux-saga-test-plan). The saga `SomeActions.someAction` calls `ToastActions.showToast` and I am trying to assert on that call. However, it is not matching the output correctly.

I don't really care about the payload being passed to `showToast`, I only care that a toast is being shown.

How do I assert on this?

Thank you!

The test:

```js
test("...", () => {
  return expectSaga(knockSaga)
    .withState(...)
    .provide(...)
    .put.actionType(ToastActions.showToast)
    .dispatch(SomeActions.someAction(...))
    .run();
});
```

The error:

```
SagaTestError: 
put expectation unmet:

Expected
--------
{
  action: {
    type: [Function: actionCreator] {
      toString: [Function (anonymous)],
      type: 'toast/showToast',
      match: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  }
}

Actual:
------
1. {
  '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  combinator: false,
  type: 'PUT',
  payload: {
    channel: undefined,
    action: {
      type: 'toast/showToast',
      payload: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.